# Blender three.js fails to import ratamahatta.js model

Tags: javascript, python, plugins, three.js, blender

We have setup the Three.js plugin for Blender (2.66)
We are getting a error when we try to import the .js model from the sample

### http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_md2.html

Error:
Read new prefs: C:\Users\anc2\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.66\
config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\BlenderInstall\Blender2.66\2.66\python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anc2\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.66\scripts\
addons\io_mesh_threejs__init__.py", line 149, in execute
    return io_mesh_threejs.import_threejs.load(self, context, **self.properties)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load'

location: :-1

location: :-1

---

PARTIAL JS model extracted from the three.js sample

{

"metadata" : {
"formatVersion" : 3.1,
"description"   : "Md 2 model converted from ratamahatta.md2 using MD2 to json converter."
},

"scale" : 1.000000,

"materials": [  {
"DbgColor" : 15658734,
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName" : "md2_material"
}],

"vertices": 4,-15.9,-3.3,10.5,-12.4,-0.8,11.4,-10.9,-1.3,12.6,-11.9,-7.6,18.1,-9.0,-3.8,16.7,-9.7,0.3,5.0,-9.0,0.0,11.3,-9.1,-1.8,9.7,-10.2,-6.0,9.5,-9.7,-10.6,12.4,-8.9,-8.0,9.9,-8.8,-2.3,15.4,-11.5],

"morphTargets": [
{ "name": "stand001", "vertices": [-2.3,4.4,3.7,-1.9,5.2,5.9,-4.9,6.4,5.5,-3.7,5.6,9.0,-0.7,1.3,4.7,0.0,1.9,7.3,-2.7,-0.6,8.6,-5.4,1.5,4.1,-7.3,5.4,3.8,-7.8,2.1,6.2,-9.4,5.2,6.0,-6.4,3.1,9.3,-7.0,5.8,8.5,-3.7,-0.8,6.0,-4.0,7.9,3.3,-2.4,11.6,4.2,-4.0,8.3,6.6,-4.9,11.8,6.9,-8.0,13.6,4.5,-5.4,15.4,6.8,-8.5,16.7,2.6,-6.0,8.7,8.3,-5.4,7.9,2.9,-8.4,9.7,5.6,-4.8,12.4,2.4,-4.5,18.9,4.4,-6.6,18.7,2.5,-2.2,17.7,1.9,-1.9,18.1,4.3,-2.8,14.6,6.6,-0.5,15.2,1.4,-2.1,17.1,-7.6,-1.4,17.3,-4.6,-0.9,18.4,-15.9,-3.3,10.5,-12.4,-0.8,11.4,-10.9,-1.3,12.6,-11.9,-7.6,18.1,-9.0,-3.8,16.7,-9.7,0.3,5.0,-9.0,0.0,11.3,-9.1,-1.8,9.7,-10.2,-6.0,9.5,-9.7,-10.6,12.4,-8.9,-8.0,9.9,-8.8,-2.3,15.4,-11.5] },
{ "name": "stand002", "vertices": [-3.2,4.3,3.6,-2.8,5.1,5.8,-5.8,6.4,5.4,-4.7,5.5,8.8,-1.7,1.2,4.7,-1.0,1.7,7.4,-4.0,-0.6,8.6,-6.4,1.6,4.0,-8.2,5.5,3.6,-8.9,2.1,6.2,-10.3,5.5,5.7,-7.6,3.1,9.2,-7.9,5.9,8.4,-4.8,-0.8,16.8,-10.0,0.1,5.1,-8.9,-0.1,11.3,-9.2,-2.0,9.8,-10.3,-6.2,9.4,-10.1,-10.9,12.3,-9.4,-8.2,10.0,-9.3,-2.5,15.2,-11.7] },
{ "name": "stand003", "vertices": [-4.1,4.1,3.5,-3.8,5.1,5.7,-6.7,6.5,5.2,-5.7,5.5,8.8,-2.8,1.0,4.8,-2.2,1.4,7.5,-5.3,-0.8,8.5,-7.4,1.6,3.8,-9.0,5.5,3.4,-9.9,2.4,6.0,-11.3,5.5,5.5,-8.7,3.4,8.9,-8.9,6.1,8.1,-6.1,-0.9,.0,-9.9,-4.3,16.9,-10.3,-0.1,5.1,-8.9,-0.4,11.4,-9.2,-2.1,9.8,-10.4,-6.3,9.4,-10.5,-11.1,12.4,-10.0,-8.3,10.0,-9.8,-2.7,15.3,-11.9] },
{ "name": "stand004", "vertices": [-4.9,4.0,3.5,-4.7,5.0,5.7,-7.4,6.5,5.0,-6.7,5.6,8.6,-3.7,0.9,4.8,-3.2,1.2,7.5,-6.5,-0.7,8.5,-8.4,1.6,3.8,-9.7,5.6,3.2,-10.9,2.6,5.8,-12.1,5.8,5.2,-9.6,3.4,8.9,-9.7,6.2,7.9,-7.2,-0.9-7.7,16.0,-16.9,-9.4,15.0,-16.1,-5.2,14.6,-16.7,-3.3,10.7,-12.9,-1.1,11.6,-11.1,-1.6,12.8,-12.3,-8.4,18.1,-10.3,-4.4,16.9,-10.4,-0.1,5.2,-8.9,-0.5,11.4,-9.0,-2.1,9.9,-10.4,-6.3,9.5,-10.8,-11.2,12.4,-10.5,-8.3,9.9,-10.2,-2.7,15.4,-12.0] },
{ "name": "stand005", "vertices": [-5.6,3.8,3.5,-5.4,4.6,5.6,-8.1,6.4,4.9,-7.3,5.4,8.6,-4.5,0.7,4.9,-4.2,1.1,7.6,-7.6,-0.9,8.,-8.1,0.2,21.9,-6.4,-6.8,20.7,-7.6,-4.3,-16.0,-10.0,0.3,-13.5,-9.0,-1.6,-17.0,-11.9,2.8,-13.3,-12.5,-3.9,-14.4,-16.8,-1.4,-16.2,-15.5,0.7,-11.9,-15.7,-4.6,-19.0,-14.8,-7.2,-19.0,-11..0,-8.5,15.8,-16.9,-5.7,15.4,-17.0,-9.8,14.1,-15.9,-8.4,21.3,-18.8,-13.8,18.0,-16.4,-1.7,19.2,-18.5,-7.2,16.0,-17.2,-8.9,15.0,-16.4,-4.8,14.6,-16.8,-3.1,10.5,-12.9,-1.0,11.7,-11.0,-1.4,12.9,-12.2,-8.3,18.0,-10.7,-4.3,17.0,-10.5,-0.1,5.2,-8.9,-0.4,11.5,-9.0,-2.0,9.9,-10.4,-6.1,9.5,-11.0,-11.1,12.3,-11.0,-8.2,9.9,-10.5,-2.5,15.4,-12.0] },
{ "name": "stand006", "vertices": [-6.0,3.5,3.6,-5.7,4.4,5.8,-8.4,6.2,4.9,-8.0,5.2,8.5,-5.0,0.3,5.0,-4.8,0.7,7.9,-8.4,-1.1,8.4,-9.6,1.3,3.5,-10.6,5.4,2.8,-12.2,2.5,5.3,-13.1,5.6,4.6,-11.1,3.5,8.5,-11.0,6.0,7.5,-8.6,-1,16.0,-17.2,-8.0,15.1,-16.6,-3.7,14.7,-16.6,-2.3,10.7,-12.7,-0.4,11.7,-10.7,-0.7,13.1,-11.9,-7.9,18.0,-10.7,-3.8,17.0,-10.4,0.2,5.2,-8.9,-0.0,11.7,-8.7,-1.4,10.0,-10.2,-5.6,9.6,-11.0,-10.5,12.1,-11.4,-7.8,10.0,-10.6,-1.9,15.7,-11.7] },
{ "name": "stand007", "vertices": [-6.1,3.1,3.6,-6.0,3.9,5.7,-8.5,6.1,4.7,-8.4,4.9,8.4,-5.3,-0.0,5.1,-5.3,0.4,7.9,-8.8,-1.4,8.1,-9.8,1.0,3.2,-10.6,5.1,2.5,-12.4,2.2,5.0,-13.3,5.3,4.2,-11.6,3.1,8.2,-11.2,5.7,7.2,-9.0,-1.4,5.2,-7.5,7.9,2.4,-6.1,11.6,3.4,-8.1,8.3,5.7,-9.0,11.8,5.7,-11.6,13.6,2.6,-9.6,15.4,5.28,-16.7,-7.4,14.2,-16.3,-6.0,21.7,-18.6,-11.5,17.9,-17.5,0.7,19.7,-17.2,-4.7,16.4,-17.1,-6.6,15.2,-16.7,-2.3,15.0,-16.2,-1.2,10.8,-12.4,0.5,12.0,-10.1,0.2,13.2,-11.3,-7.1,18.1,-10.8,-3.1,17.1,-10.0,0.7,5.3,-8.8,0.6,11.8,-8.4,-0.7,10.0,-10.0,-4.9,9.7,-10.9,-9.4,12.2,-11.8,-7.1,9.8,-10.6,-0.9,15.8,-11.3] },
{ "name": "stand008", "vertices": [-6.0,2.7,3.7,-6.0,3.7,5.7,-8.4,5.7,4.6,-8.6,4.5,8.3,-5.2,-0.4,5.1,-5.4,-0.1,7.9,-9.2,-1.8,7.8,-9.6,0.7,3.1,-10.5,4.9,2.2,-12.4,1.9,4.5,-13.2,5.1,3.8,-11.8,2.7,7.8,-11.4,5.5,7.0,-8.92,17.1,-9.6,1.4,5.5,-8.8,1.4,11.9,-8.1,0.1,10.2,-9.8,-4.0,9.6,-10.7,-8.3,12.1,-11.8,-6.3,9.8,-10.5,-0.1,15.9,-10.7] },
{ "name": "stand009", "vertices": [-5.8,2.4,3.6,-6.0,3.2,5.8,-8.3,5.3,4.5,-8.5,3.9,8.2,-5.1,-0.8,5.2,-5.6,-0.6,8.0,-9.1,-2.3,7.6,-9.5,0.4,2.9,-10.2,4.5,2.1,-12.3,1.6,4.2,-13.0,4.7,3.5,-11.7,2.4,7.5,-11.4,4.9,6.8,-8.9,-2.3,4.7,-7.2,7.3,2.3,-6.0,11.2,3.5,-8.2,7.7,5.6,-9.2,11.2,5.6,-11.5,12.7,2.3,-9.8,14.5,5..5,-16.4,0.1,15.3,-15.2,0.9,11.2,-11.5,2.2,12.2,-9.1,2.0,13.5,-10.2,-5.4,18.0,-10.5,-1.6,17.1,-9.2,1.8,5.3,-8.6,1.8,11.8,-7.8,0.6,10.2,-9.5,-3.4,9.6,-10.6,-7.5,12.2,-11.9,-5.7,9.8,-10.3,0.7,15.9,-10.2] },
{ "name": "stand010", "vertices": [-5.6,2.0,3.8,-5.8,2.8,5.9,-8.1,5.0,4.6,-8.4,3.6,8.4,-4.8,-1.1,5.3,-5.3,-0.9,8.1,-8.9,-2.6,7.8,-9.2,-0.1,3.0,-10.0,4.2,2.2,-12.0,1.1,4.4,-12.8,4.2,3.6,-11.5,1.8,7.6,-11.2,4.6,6.8,-8.}